# Flex Clipboard does not work with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, apache-flex, clipboard

I need to copy some data to the system clipboard in Flex, so it can be copied into Excel. When a user clicks a button, the click handler will call a method that generates the Excel HTML data and copies it to the clipboard (approximately 2.5 MB data).

I have tried two approaches:

```
System.setClipboard(xml.toString());
```

and

```
Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT, xml.toString());
```

The data is correctly copied to the clipboard when I run the application in Internet Explorer 11 (32 bit) and Firefox, but in Chrome it does not copy the data.

---

> Chrome 36.0.1985.143 m 
>   Flash 14.0.0.177
>   Flex version: 4.6.0

---

**EDIT:** It should be noted that copying to the clipboard from Flex using Chrome works for small copies (tested with 4KB). Am I hitting some sort of limit on Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding a 'wmode' parameter in your html template file and then setting that to 'direct'?

```
var params = {};
        params.wmode = "direct";
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still does not work. Copying to the clipboard in Chrome works for smaller data (and this is the case using either "direct" or "transparent" windows mode).